# Check whether the following is a subgroup of S4

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G=S_4$ and $U=\{\sigma \in S_4 | σ^2=(1)\}$

Prove or disprove that $U$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I tried this:

Let $a,b \in U$. Because $(ab)^2 =(1):$

$$ab=(ab)^{-1}=abab=ab(ab)^{-1} =(1)$$

Is my proof totally wrong , can it be saved somehow?. If not please give me some tips on how to do it correctly. I want this question to be solved by the subgroup criteria.

Answer (score 3):

Quick way: $((12) (13))^{2} \ne 1$, so it's not a subgroup.

But why did I choose those two elements? Well, if $a^{2} = b^{2} = 1$, then $(a b)^{2}  = 1$ implies $1 = a b a b = a b a^{-1} b^{-1}$, whence $ab = ba$.

So I have chosen $a = (12)$ and $b = (13)$ because $ab \ne ba$.

Comment: Thank you... I feel so bad for not realizing this...

Comment: You're welcome, and no problem. Experimenting a bit is always useful.

Comment: Could you explain this step ?  1=abab=aba^-1 b^-1 whence ab=ba